Pass a large object to render in Express Layout
I'm using Express layouts to render my webpage when a certain route is used:
The project I'm building is an admin panel, where I edit a huge table of data (think of a products management website for example, where you have thousands of entries)


const express = require('express')
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const app = express();
app.use(expressLayouts)

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render(
    'myView', 
    myLargeObject // my object I'm passing to the client to build elements from
  )
})



Inside a .ejs file, I'm loading the data into the client side like so:


var data = '<%- JSON.stringify(myLargeObject) %>';



Inside index.js, I'm parsing the string back to an object {} in order to construct html elements:


function init() {
  const myData = JSON.parse(data);
  // building html elements using the data
}



My problem arises when the object I pass gets too large. It's simply unable to process it past a certain length.
My question is how to load my webpage with all of the data at once. I've considered pagination, but I need all of the data displayed on the screen at once.
Any advice?

It seems like you're contemplating a user interface where you send huge amounts of data to the browser (as JSON), parse that huge data into a client-side JavaScript object and then display all that huge data at once.  That type of design is not considering the practical aspects of doing it that way (bandwidth costs and transfer time), the client aspects of doing it that way (very large memory consumption) and the interface aspects (the user can't possible look at all that data at once anyway).  Imagine trying to use this in the memory constraints or bandwidth speed/cost of a phone?

Clients don't have unlimited memory or bandwidth or download speed. You probably need a better design that doesn't, by default, transfer that much data from the server to client before the client has even viewed your page and a design where data is fetched as needed by the user in their interface.

"I need all of the data displayed on the screen at once".  No, you don't.  You just need a different user interface to interact with the data.

Load the content asynchronously.
First prepare an additional endpoint like:
app.get('/api/data', (request, response) => {
  response.json(myLargeObject);
});

Then in you client:
async function init() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/data');
  const myData = await response.json();
  // building html elements using the data
}


If I understood you correctly I should:

Use res.render() to render my main layout
Create another route from which to send the json I intend to pass to the client
Build my html elements with the data sent from said route

And this approach guarantees there won't be any limitations to the size of the passed json
However, I've now just noticed, that I also build some elements inside .ejs (and not only inside my index.js) - so would that be possible to handle the fetch inside .ejs? (I intend to move all of the html elements creation there)

Choose just one approach, either server side rendering via ejs or client side via your script. If you need to render thousands of elements you'll need pagination anyhow (to reduce the user cognitive load at least).
